# Google Drive (googlesyncdrive) preventing PC from shutting down or hibernating

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, hibernate, google-drive

Everytime I try to shutdown or hibernate the PC I have this nag screen that comes up telling me that Google Drive is shutting down and the system is waiting for it. The problem is that the system can wait endlessly for Google Drive to finish syncing up.

> Google Drive is shutting down. Please wait.

[image: screenshot]

This causes problems when the power goes and my system is running on the UPS. Hibernation keeps waiting for 7 minutes before the UPS dies.

**How can I get Windows 7 to force hibernation and ignore these applications?**

I understand fully that this will cause be data lost but thanks to Google Drive it will get lost either way. At least I'll save my UPS this way.

**OR, How can I modify / tweak Google Drive to not prevent the shutdown the next time?**

Comment: This happens to me too, especially when there is no Wi-Fi/internet connection. All I can do is manually close Google Drive and then press shutdown again. Have you found a way?

Comment: I had this problem as well but recently it just disappeared and google drive quits quickly...

Comment: @rluks I just uninstalled google drive and finally switched to dropbox which was much more reliable. Another problem that I had seen in Google Drive was with syncing office documents as they got larger. For some reason Google Drive would remain idle for a while and then suddenly wake up and start uploading. Yet, it was constantly using a notable CPU percentage. I've never looked back at this badly coded piece of junk after using Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a good answer, great; if not, an ugly answer would be a scheduled task.

Create a scheduled task (in the Task Scheduler) to run the Force shutdown command when a certain event is logged. Finding the correct event (in the Event Viewer) may prove difficult, but it could be worth your time. Maybe an event showing that your UPS requested a shutdown, or an event showing the request for Google Drive to stop. Something like that. When that event happens, the Scheduled task will trigger the force shutdown.

Force shutdown command:

> shutdown -s -t 0 -f

Comment: Scheduling a force hibernate is not the right solution. I need to do this when when there is a power outage and my system is running on the UPS. Hibernation keeps waiting for 7 minutes before the UPS dies. My display isn't accessible for that duration.

Answer (score 0):

Simply click on force shut down and don't afraid to do so no data loss will happen and everything will be alright

you can also press ctrl+shift+esc to open task manager go to process and kill it manually and then opt for shut down

Comment: Clicking on force shut down is not the right solution. I've mentioned in the question that this cannot be done when there is a power outage because my screen siwitches off. My system cannot hibernate while google sync is blocking it.