# Google Drive Prevents Windows Shutdown

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, google-drive, windows-error-reporting

This is a similar question to [Google Drive (googlesyncdrive) preventing PC from shutting down or hibernating](https://superuser.com/questions/1074232/google-drive-googlesyncdrive-preventing-pc-from-shutting-down-or-hibernating) - however, it is different since this time it is Windows 10 (not 7) and I actually get an error message, which is the following:

[image]

How can I prevent this Application Error?

Comment: This error appears not everytime I shutdown, but very often.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in the linked question?  Just because you're using Win10 and have an error message, doesn't mean those solutions won't work.

Comment: I don't like the "force shutdown" workarount. I'm looking for a clean solution.